# Creating the cartesian product of two lists into a new list in C

Tags: c, arrays, cartesian-product

I want to create an array that is the cartesian product of two arrays. So for example:

```
const char *first[] = {"1", "2","3"};
const char *second[] = { "a" , "b" , "c", "e"};
```

The result is the array:

```
Cartesian = {"(1,a)","(1,b)","(1,c)",....};
```

This is what I have for now:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char *first[] = {"1", "2","3"};
    const char *second[] = { "a" , "b" , "c", "e"};

    int size = sizeof(first) * sizeof(second);

    char *both[size];
    int i=0;

    for (int f=0; f<sizeof(first); f++) {  
       for (int s=0; s<sizeof(second); s++) {
          char *temp[size];
           strcpy(temp[s], "("+first[f]+ ","second[s]+")");
           both[i] = temp;
           i++;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `strcpy(temp[s], "("+first[f]+ ","second[s]+")");`? You can't concatenate strings using the `+` operator. And `temp[s]` has no memory allocated. Use `sprintf(temp[s], "(%s,%s)",first[f],second[s]);` after allocating memory.

Comment: `sizeof(first)` --> `sizeof(first) / sizeof(*first)`

Comment: You have to study how arrays work before doing this. C has no magic string class, it needs to allocate arrays in valid read/write memory. Your code does not allocate any memory, so at best the program will crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problems in your code:

1. `sizeof(first)`(and `sizeof(second)`) gives `number of string literals in the array * sizeof(char*)`. You need to discard the second part. Just divide it by `sizeof(char*)` or `sizeof(*str)` as [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123677/creating-the-cartesian-product-of-two-lists-into-a-new-list-in-c#comment48357011_30123677) which is the same as `sizeof(str[0])`:

   ```
   int size = (sizeof(first) / sizeof(*first)) * (sizeof(second) / sizeof(*second));
   ```
2. Your loops:

   ```
   for (int f=0; f<sizeof(first); f++)
   for (int s=0; s<sizeof(second); s++)
   ```

   suffer the same problem. I suggest using

   ```
   int size1 = sizeof(first) / sizeof(*first);
   int size2 = sizeof(second) / sizeof(*second)

   for (int f=0; f < size1; f++)
   for (int s=0; s < size2; s++)
   ```
3. Your body of the loop has many problems. Remove everything from it. The following steps show what to do there.

## Steps to resolve the problems:

1. You need to allocate memory for `char *both[size];`. Allocate memory from the body of the loop:

   ```
   int i=0;

   for (int f=0; f < size1; f++)
   {
       for (int s=0; s < size2; s++)
       {
           both[i] = malloc(strlen(first[f]) + strlen(second[s]) + 4);
           /*Mallocing space for two brackets, a comma, a NUL-terminator and the coordinates*/
           i++; //Increment counter
       }
   }
   ```
2. `strcpy` is the wrong function to use here. Use `sprintf` instead:

   ```
   int i=0;

   for (int f=0; f < size1; f++)
   {
       for (int s=0; s < size2; s++)
       {
           both[i] = malloc(strlen(first[f]) + strlen(second[s]) + 4);

           sprintf(both[i], "(%s,%s)",first[f],second[s]); // Make the string
           i++;
       }
   }
   ```
3. After the loop, `both` is populated according to your needs. Print them using:

   ```
   for(int j=0; j<i ; j++)
       printf("%s \n",both[j]);
   ```
4. After its use, `free` the allocated memory using:

   ```
   for(int j=0; j<i ; j++)
       free(both[j]);
   ```

## Fixed program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //For malloc and free
#include <string.h> //For strlen

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char *first[] = {"1", "2","3"};
    const char *second[] = { "a" , "b" , "c", "e"};

    int size = (sizeof(first) / sizeof(*first)) * (sizeof(second) / sizeof(*second));

    char *both[size];
    int i=0;

    int size1 = sizeof(first) / sizeof(*first);
    int size2 = sizeof(second) / sizeof(*second)

    for (int f=0; f < size1; f++)
    {
        for (int s=0; s < size2; s++)
        {
            both[i] = malloc(strlen(first[f]) + strlen(second[s]) + 4);
            sprintf(both[i], "(%s,%s)",first[f],second[s]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<i ; j++)
        printf("%s\n",both[j]);

    for(int j=0; j<i ; j++)
        free(both[j]);

    return 0; //or return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

## Other notes:

- Check the result of `malloc` to see if it was successful in allocating memory. `malloc` returns `NULL` on failure.
- Checking the result of `sprintf` is also good, although not neccessary. `sprintf` returns a negative number on failure.

Answer (score 1):

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *first[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
    const char *second[] = { "a" , "b" , "c", "e" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( first ) / sizeof( *first );
    const size_t M = sizeof( second ) / sizeof( *second );
    char product[N * M][3];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            strcpy( product[i*M + j], first[i] );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], second[j] );
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * M; i++ ) printf( "%s ", product[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1a 1b 1c 1e 2a 2b 2c 2e 3a 3b 3c 3e
```

If you want to enclose each string in parentheses then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *first[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
    const char *second[] = { "a" , "b" , "c", "e" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( first ) / sizeof( *first );
    const size_t M = sizeof( second ) / sizeof( *second );
    char product[N * M][6];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            strcpy( product[i*M + j], "(" );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], first[i] );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], "," );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], second[j] );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], ")" );
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * M; i++ ) printf( "%s ", product[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
(1,a) (1,b) (1,c) (1,e) (2,a) (2,b) (2,c) (2,e) (3,a) (3,b) (3,c) (3,e)
```

Also the loops

```
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            strcpy( product[i*M + j], "(" );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], first[i] );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], "," );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], second[j] );
            strcat( product[i*M + j], ")" );
        }
    }
```

can be written simpler using `sprintf` (or even `snprintf`)

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
    {
        sprintf( product[i*M + j], "(%s,%s)", first[i], second[j] );
    }
}
```